# Call to a member function modify() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

So I'm trying to check if the reset link is expired. Here's what I got

```
//Get token data
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT token_created_at from reset WHERE token = :urltoken");
$stmt->bindValue(':urltoken', htmlspecialchars($_GET['token'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $token_created_at = $row['token_created_at'];
}

$token_created_at;

//Return current time to match
$current_time = new DateTime(); 

$my_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $token_created_at);

//Modify error
$expires_at = $my_dt->modify('+1 hour');
```

And how I set the date when the user asks for a reset

```
//Get creation time 
$time_gen = date('m-d-Y H:i:s', time());
```

Now what happens is I get

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function modify() on a non-object  in /Users/MATT/Desktop/Learn/forgot/activate.php on line 26

Line 26 being

```
$expires_at = $my_dt->modify('+1 hour');
```

Any ideas? I've tried other posts, but they don't seem to apply to my issue. They're also stored as `VARCHAR`

Comment: If `DateTime::createFromFormat` gets an error it returns `false`. You need to check for this.

Comment: What does `echo $token_created_at` show?

Comment: If that's a `datetime` column, the date will be in `Y-m-d` format, not `m-d-Y`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the issue is with `$row['token_created_at']`

Comment: @Barmar `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. It's also VARCHAR

Comment: You say your column is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` so why are you doing `createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s'`. It should be `createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s'`. Also, since it is already `0000-00-00 00:00:00` you should change it from `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-returnvalues):

> > **DateTime::createFromFormat Return Values**
> >
> > Returns a new `DateTime` instance or `FALSE` on failure.

So your `$my_dt` variable is very likely `FALSE`, which would definitely cause that error.

Your time format string probably needs to be `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` if you're using the standard MySQL `DATETIME` type.